# How to fix LSTM keras api 2 warning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a LSTM model using keras. I am getting this warning message while executing the code. How to update my  `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API ?

This is the warning message that I am receving.

> lstm.py:32: UserWarning: Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API:
>   `LSTM(256, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.28)`
>   model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout_U=0.28, dropout_W=0.25))

```
embed_dim = 256
  lstm_out = 256
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embed_dim,input_length = maxlen))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.28))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout_U=0.28, dropout_W=0.25))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is written on the message.

```
LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.28)
```